# mod_rewrite: how to redirect everything except 2 files to "/"?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a bit of a problem with a mod_rewrite configuration.

I want to redirect everything to the root directory (http://www.mydomain.com/), except for two files.

So I tried this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/file1.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/file2.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/ [L,R=301]
```

This unfortunetely doesn't redirect anything.

If I leave out the first RewriteCond line, I get a redirection error.

Where did I go wrong here?

Answer (score 9):

First, you'll probably want to use `REQUEST_URI` instead of `REQUEST_FILENAME`. They may be the same in a virtual host scenario, but not normally. You're probably meaning to rewrite the URI, not the local path.

Secondly, your rule;

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^/
```

...excludes all requests to something *starting with `/`*, that is *all* URIs, from being rewritten. What you'll want to do is probably;

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
```

The rules for the ignored files should probably have an additional `$` at the end to be an "ends with" match instead of a "contains" match.

That leaves something like;

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/file1.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/file2.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I found it myself! It was quite the same as you suggested, Joachim - but thanks anyway!